# Why does collect() on a DataFrame with 1 row use 2000 exectors?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, distributed

This is the simplest DataFrame I could think of. I'm using PySpark 1.6.1.

```
# one row of data
rows = [ (1,   2) ]
cols = [ "a", "b" ]
df   = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, cols)
```

So the data frame completely fits in memory, has no references to any files and looks quite trivial to me.

Yet when I collect the data, it uses 2000 executors:

```
df.collect()
```

during collect, 2000 executors are used:

```
[Stage 2:===================================================>(1985 + 15) / 2000]
```

and then the expected output:

```
[Row(a=1, b=2)]
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the DataFrame be completely in memory on the driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I looked into the code a bit to try to figure out what was going on. It seems that `sqlContext.createDataFrame` really does not make any kind of attempt to set reasonable parameter values based on the data.

**Why 2000 tasks?**

Spark uses 2000 tasks because my data frame had 2000 partitions. (Even though it seems like clear nonsense to have more partitions than rows.)

This can be seen by:

```
>>> df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
2000
```

**Why did the DataFrame have 2000 partitions?**

This happens because `sqlContext.createDataFrame` winds up using the default number of partitions (2000 in my case), irrespective of how the data is organized or how many rows it has.

The code trail is as follows.

In `sql/context.py`, the `sqlContext.createDataFrame` function calls (in this example):

```
rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(data, schema)
```

which in turn calls:

```
return self._sc.parallelize(data), schema
```

And the `sqlContext.parallelize` function is defined in `context.py`:

```
numSlices = int(numSlices) if numSlices is not None else self.defaultParallelism
```

No check is done on the number of rows, and it is not possible to specify the number of slices from `sqlContext.createDataFrame`.

**How can I change how many partitions the DataFrame has?**

Using `DataFrame.coalesce`.

```
>>> smdf = df.coalesce(1)
>>> smdf.rdd.getNumPartitions()
1
>>> smdf.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
Coalesce 1
+- Scan ExistingRDD[a#0L,b#1L]
>>> smdf.collect()
[Row(a=1, b=2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the number of executors. In many cases, spark will take as many executors as available, and execution time is a lot worse than when you limit to a small number of executors.

```
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled','true')
conf.set('spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors','32')
```

Comment: Ok.. but why would this be one of the many cases where it uses many executors? There are no distributed files and the DataFrame fits in memory. I would have expected it to use 0 (or maybe 1) executor.

Comment: It depends on your sparkconf more than on the job itself

Comment: Huh. I'm a bit shocked that Spark isn't more intelligent about resource management. I would have thought it was trying to process each distributed data partition on the node closest to where that partition is stored. So the case with no distributed data would be pretty trivial. I guess I misunderstand what Spark's manager does...